# Existe um XHTML5 (XHTML + HTML5)?

Tags: html, html5, xhtml

O XHTML é o HTML com sintaxe estrita (precisa ser um XML válido).

Consigo usá-lo em conjunto com o HTML5?

Comment: Não, pois tinhamos 2 caminhos: XHTML2 e HTML5, e infelizmente prevaleceu o 2o, pois os comitês e empresas envolvidos acharam que era melhor qualquer um conseguir por qualquer coisa no ar, em vez de fazer com que as pessoas aprendam o mínimo necessário para publicar coisas consistentes. Pior é que esse pensamento anda "na moda", dá até alguns discursos bonitos por aí.

Comment: [maybe](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-xml-xhtml-5/) existam ["documentos poliglotas"](http://tableless.com.br/documentos-poliglotas-com-xhtml5/).

Comment: @renan pior que isso ai só deixa a situação mais feia.

Comment: @renan de qualquer forma é bom pra constar, de repente atende à necessidade do OP. Eu particularmente não gosto por não ter as vantagens que o XHTML teria, que é o browser não mostrar conteúdo malformado.

Comment: Talvez isso pode te ajudart http://www.standardista.com/html5-v-xhtml5/

Answer (score 7):

Não existe um XHTML + HTML5.
O XHTML foi um caminho tomado pelo W3C para tentar restringir o padrão de código da internet toda. A ideia era que todo mundo escrevesse código válido e semântico. O HTML5, por sua vez, é uma atualização da linguagem iniciada por um grupo de desenvolvedores ligados a empresas como Apple, Google e Firefox.

Você consegue escrever sintaxe XHTML (que não tem tanta diferença assim) no HTML5 tranquilamente. O validador do W3C não vai reclamar da sintaxe. Mas é uma ótima prática não misturar os dois.

Comment: Por que não misturar os dois? Eu também evito isso, mas não sei bem explicar o motivo.

Answer (score 3):

O XHTML tem um padrão e é validado com base no HTML mais antigo, o que não inclui alguns novos inputs do html5 e algumas sintaxes de metatags, infelizmente ainda o XHTML é baseado no HTML2, seguindo suas sintaxes e validações, o que é muito importante para as IDES e Servidores poderem validar seu código, diferente do que se vê hoje em PHP por exemplo(desenvolvi 8 anos nessa linguagem), q é aquele monte de gambiarra e código mal feito. Com validação baseada em um padrão é possível um código mais legível a todos.
 Aguardamos ansiosamente uma definição da JSP com sintaxes de HTML5. Até lá é se virar com o velhro XHTML, CSS e JQuery.

Comment: "XHTML é baseado no HTML2"? Você tem alguma referência para sustentar essa afirmação?

Comment: Desculpe a confusao, o XHTML é baseado no HTML4.

Answer (score 2):

Acho interessante você entender o que é especificação e implementação.

XHTML 4.x, HTML5 são especificações, são um conjunto de regras que definem como o HTML deve ser interpretado pelos navegadores, é algo análogo à norma culta da lingua portuguesa.

Implementação é como os navegadores de fato interpretam, o que geralmente difere em um ponto ou outro dependendo do navegador, é análogo ao português falado.

Historicamente o XHTML não colou, a maioria dos navegadores não se importava muito com a especificação do XHTML, em boa parte devido à algumas regras meio chatas do XHTMl como ter de definir um doctype com uma url que ninguém lembrava, ter de fechar tags solitárias como por exemplo o `<br>` que tinha de ser escrito como `<br />` segundo a especificação do XHTML. Para os navegadores era mais importante fazer o código que as pessoas escreviam funcionar do que seguir a especificação xarope do XHTML.

Com base nisso foi criado o HTML5, que é uma especificação mais próxima do que os navegadores implementam, que é o que realmente importa.

Em boa parte foi pressão dos navegadores em fazer uma especificação funcional, mas especificamente de um grupo chamado [WHATWG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Hypertext_Application_Technology_Working_Group) .

tl;dr: não existe xhtml5.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do Erik:

- o W3C fechou/dissolveu/desmanchou o grupo de trabalho do XHTML2 em 2009. Em 2007 eles já haviam reconhecido o HTML5 como o então próximo padrão de HTML. Portanto, nem se incomode com o XHTML2.
- o HTML5 possui tanto o text/html regular como o application/xhtml+xml p/ servir a página.

https://www.w3.org/2009/06/xhtml-faq.html

Note ali na página:

> Regarding the XML serialization of HTML, the HTML 5 specification
>   includes a section on XML serialization, as well as a section on
>   text/html serialization. W3C plans to continue work on both
>   serializations in the HTML Working Group. Thus, we expect the next
>   generation XML serialization of HTML to be defined in the HTML 5
>   specification. Currently, the HTML 5 specification refers to this
>   serialization as "XHTML 5"

Sim, existe o tal XHTML5. Pelo menos como uma forma de serializar a página definida numa seção do padrão. Como o próprio W3C diz, o text/html é suficiente p/ a maior parte dos casos (e o que se usa hoje com o DOCTYPE html)

Se vc quiser matar a curiosidade com um material da época:

http://www.standardista.com/html5-v-xhtml5/

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhtml5

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-xml-xhtml-5/

http://xmlplease.com/xhtml/xhtml5polyglot/

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-think45/