# Existe o XHTML5?

Tags: html5, xhtml

Faço essa pergunta pois baseado em outras duas perguntas não cheguei a entender uma solução.

A primeira seria essa: [Quando usar o atributo xmlns no elemento html?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119348/quando-usar-o-atributo-xmlns-no-elemento-html)

No caso, a resposta aceita foi dada pelo @tayllan

> No seu exemplo, xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" indica que a
>   sintaxe utilizada no documento é na verdade XHTML5 e não HTML5.

Indo procurar mais sobre o **XHTML5** vejo essa pergunta também no SOpt: [Existe um XHTML5 (XHTML + HTML5)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56655/existe-um-xhtml5-xhtml-html5)

> Não existe um XHTML + HTML5. O XHTML foi um caminho tomado pelo W3C
>   para tentar restringir o padrão de código da internet toda. A ideia
>   era que todo mundo escrevesse código válido e semântico. O HTML5, por
>   sua vez, é uma atualização da linguagem iniciada por um grupo de
>   desenvolvedores ligados a empresas como Apple, Google e Firefox.

Então, refazendo as perguntas:

- **Existe XHTML5?**
- **Qual a real utilidade do parâmetro** xmlns em um documento HTML5?

Comment: E está refazendo as perguntas elas são duplicatas. Se não está satisfeito co mas respostas coloque recompensa nelas.

Answer (score -1):

> If you want to code HTML5 yet still use valid XML syntax and headers, and serve your document as XML, you’re coding XHTML5: it seems that ‘XHTML5’ has become an official name of HTML5 coded and served as XML, since the original term "Polyglot Markup" never took off.
>
> XHTML5 is a document that conforms to both the HTML and XHTML syntax by using a common subset of both the HTML and XHTML. To code XHTML5 you need to:
>
> Use the HTML5 doctype
>   Code in XHTML well-formed syntax
>   Default XHTML namespace: 
>   A server that serves up files as XML MIME type application/xhtml+xml
>   An XHTML5 document can be served as either HTML or XHTML, depending on browser support and MIME type. It really only becomes XHTML5 document if it is served with the XML MIME type application/xhtml+xml . Otherwise, it is just really well coded HTML5
>
> For a document to be XML, you need a server that serves up the file as XML MIME type: application/xhtml+xml. This MIME declaration is not visible in the source code. If you want to check how you file is served, check the HTTP Content-Type header. The XML MIME type is not yet supported by Internet Explorer, but IE can render XHTML documents.

- Sendo direto, "existe em partes". Você pode considerar uma mistura de comandos com o HTML5.
- aqui tem uma boa descrição pra sua pergunta, tem algumas explicações sobre o xlmns:
  [O que são namespaces no XML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140264/o-que-s%C3%A3o-namespaces-no-xml)